# Problems to create new tables when the database already exists

Tags: android, sqlite, create-table

I'm having some strange behaviour.
If the database does not exists, and i execute the following code in my Activity:

```
listOpenHelper = new ListOpenHelper(ManageListActivity.this);
db = listOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query(ListOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, BaseColumns._ID + " DESC");
```

The database is create and the table LIST is created, no problem here.

The problem is when i try to execute a similiar block in other Activity:

```
productListOpenHelper = new ProductListOpenHelper(ProductListActivity.this);
db = productListOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query(ProductListOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, ProductListOpenHelper.NAME + " ASC");
```

In this case, i get the Exception "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: list: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM list ORDER BY _id DESC"

If i erase the database and execute first the above block, and after the first block, the error will be in the productlist table.

I need to create all my tables in the first execution? 
I like to create the tables when the user enter in each of the Activities, there is some good way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to delete and re-create tables every time a user opens another activity? The whole purpose of a database is to ... store data.

Comment: I didn't delete and re-create, i created one time, the problem is when i try to create another table in a existing database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different databases, correct?  If not, you *probably* shouldn't have two different helper classes.

Also, creating helpers as you are *may* not be ideal.  See blog post:

http://www.touchlab.co/blog/single-sqlite-connection/

Please post the code for your helper classes and why you have two different classes.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! I have only one database, i will read this site you post to learn how i can create the DB's better, and if i have some problem, i post the code from my Helper's here.

Answer (score 0):

why you are using two different helpers? i don't think its a good way... You can create the tables in the initially and you can obtain the db whenever you want, with a single helper.